# One of our customers is experiencing a 504 error, where is that to occur?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, gateway, 504

One of our customers is having some problems accessing our web site. They've got 2 machines, and each of them is experiencing different symptoms, but I suspect that even though they're experiencing different symptoms, somehow they might be related to the same cause. I'll discuss the one where I got the most information. On that PC I installed Fiddler 2, and watched the HTTP traffic. I found an add-on that was interfering (something called "Solid Savings") which I disabled. That got me further, but not much. Next I got an error that just stopped me cold; it was an HTTP 504 error. I looked that error up and found that it stands for "Gateway time out". That's nice, but what I don't know is which gateway? Is it our customer's gateway, or is it our gateway?

Comment: Typically this is returned by a proxy server that's unable to contact  a requested server, or a browser that's unable to reach a proxy server.  Are your customer's systems configured to use a proxy server? Or is there a transparent proxy server on their network?  Does your website have a reverse proxy in front of it?  Did you remember to configure the software *not* to use Fiddler 2 once you were done using it?

Comment: I don't know whether the customer's systems are configured to use a proxy server or not, I'll have to ask them. I'll also ask our system admin and CenturyLink about our network. I don't believe I did set the customer's to not use Fiddler 2, thank you for reminding me of that, as well as the rest of your feedback.